# How to get calculate/retry day 7 retention from Flurry analytics

Tags: analytics, flurry

I am wondering what is the best/easiest way to get day 7 retention using flurry analytics.

I am looking for retention defined as users who used app on this specific day.

Flurry offers Rolling retention (lifecycle) which defines day 7 retention as users who logged on day 7 or later. Second option - User retention - defines day 7 retention as users who logged on day 7 or 7 days earlier or later.

Thanks,

Comment: If install date cohorts can satisfy your need for now, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428731/how-can-i-measure-retention-using-google-analytics-mobile-sdk/17636689#17636689).